# Max amount of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Model where I save settings for the app - AppConfiguration.

How would I prevent that more than one object instance of the model is created?

Comment: Do you mean there can only be one record of model ConfigFoo in the database?  Or is it that there's only one ConfigFoo per app, and you have a different table for Apps?  If it is literally one record for the entire rails app then it sounds like it would be better off in a config file rather than the db.

Comment: It is literally one record. My app is deployed on different servers: Production, Staging, Demo - and my wish is to set/change (different) app-wide settings from the console for each server.

Comment: Yep, then use config files, one for each environment.

Comment: Or indeed use the environment files, under `config/environment` - then define the rails environment when deploying.